# Is there a way I can find an element in a FlatList using Detox E2E testing

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs, mocha.js, detox

So while testing my application, I am using a data set. Since the data set has many entries, I am using FlatList to display my list. After creating the list, I want to be able to verify and tap on certain list items. Below, I have attached the code which I am trying to use and it does not work for me. If anyone has a better idea to do this, please let me know.

The approach I think should be taken. I can't think of anything else to make the FlatList scroll and find the item I am looking for.

```
let isNotFound = true;
while (isNotFound) {
   try {
       await waitFor(element(by.id((edit_details.index).toString()))).toBeVisible().withTimeout(2000)
       isNotFound = false;
   } catch (e) {
       await element(by.id('credit_history_list')).swipe('up', 'slow', 0.2)
   }
}
await element(by.id((edit_details.index).toString())).tap();
```

It does help scroll the list and it keeps scrolling while it actually finds the entry I am looking for. But the .tap() function does not work. Instead, detox moves on with the next line of code.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds spot-on with Detox' [`whileElement()` API](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.ActionsOnElement.md#whileelementelement).

I think that what you're looking for is this:

```js
const itemId = (edit_details.index).toString();
const listId = 'credit_history_list';
await waitFor(element(by.id(itemId))).toBeVisible()
        .whileElement(by.id(listId))
        .scroll(100, 'down');
```

Comment: Thank you so much @d4vidi !! This really helps, however, if I want to tap on an element, it gives me the error that the view is not 75% visible. So I have put that 'tap()' function inside a try and catch block. If the view is not 75% visible, it scrolls an extra 50 pixel to make it visible. Is that the correct approach? Let me know if it is not clear, I will put up a snippet as well

Comment: @MuhammadHasanKhan Yes I see nothing wrong with the approach. If it passes the use case, It's great.

Comment: @MuhammadHasanKhan I don't understand how that can be. If you're on Android, using `toBeVisible()`+`scroll` inherently translates to a 75% visibility assertion. Could you perhaps create a use cases in a small app, and submit as a bug? Are you in fact, on iOS?